# How to send string contains HTML to SOAP xml?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

How to pass string in SOAP xml web service. My string contains HTML format. When I click on submit xml give me output, but I can't retrieve data. Instead of string (not HTML) I got perfect response. My code is,

```
string = @"<table class=\"\" style=\"width: 100%;\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">"
 "        <tr>"
 "<td bgcolor=\"#7ea34b\" height=\"88\" style=\"padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt;color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana\" align=\"center\">"
 "Book Your New Car @ <a href=\"http://www.test.com/\">www.test.com</a>"
 "or Call 123456789 <br />"
 "<a href=\"http://www.test.com//unsubscribe.aspx?email="
 "\">Click Here</a>"
"to Unsubscribe from this List" "</td></tr>"
"</table> </table>";
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap the HTML in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` so the `string` looks like this:

```
string = @"<![CDATA[<table class=\"\" style=\"width: 100%;\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">"
 "        <tr>"
 "<td bgcolor=\"#7ea34b\" height=\"88\" style=\"padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt;color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana\" align=\"center\">"
 "Book Your New Car @ <a href=\"http://www.test.com/\">www.test.com</a>"
 "or Call 1-888-284-4718<br />"
 "<a href=\"http://www.test.com//unsubscribe.aspx?email="
 "\">Click Here</a>"
"to Unsubscribe from this List" "</td></tr>"
"</table> </table>]]>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can encode the string to base64 on client side and then decode it on the server side. This way you don't need to worry about the quotes.